# Setting delegates to nil in viewWillDisappear?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, delegates

Should I set delegates to nil when a view controller calls viewWillDisappear? Of course, set up the delegate again when viewWillAppear is called.

What happens to the delegate and its calls when a viewcontroller is not active but the delegate is still set to sent messages to the viewcontroller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really depends on your use case. If you want the view controller to **ignore** delegate callbacks while it is not on screen, then sure you can nil out the delegate in `viewWillDisappear`. However, I have found this to be dangerous in some cases. Consider, UITableView dataSource. If you nil out the dataSource in viewWillDisappear, then for some reason you try to `reloadData` while is view is out of view, the table view will not reload correctly.

I usually like to only nil out in `dealloc`.